# javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find 'ENTITY' with id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have got 3 tables: Database, Table, Field. They are connected with one-to-many reletionalship. 
Database one-to-many Table one-to-many Field.
But when I'm invoking save method from jpa repository, I'm getting next exception. Also I was checking answers on stackowerflow. And adding annotation @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) on Many-To-One relationship didn't help.

> Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.domain.Table with id 79fa34b6-b2e7-4c13-a4c8-e8f216a4b4c7 at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:158) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1122) at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:646) at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431) at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:330) at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:543) at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:688) at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.replace(AbstractType.java:144) at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replaceAssociations(TypeHelper.java:264) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:420) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:240) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:301) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:170) at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:883) at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:869) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy150.merge(Unknown Source) at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:511) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489) at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ... 141 common frames omitted

Database class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "data_base", schema = "dbmanager")
public class Database {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_database", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "database_url")
    private String databaseUrl;

    @Column(name = "database_user")
    private String databaseUser;

    @Column(name = "database_password")
    private String databasePassword;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "database")
    private Set<Table> tables;
    }
```

Table class:

```
    @Entity
    @javax.persistence.Table(name = "data_base_table", schema = "dbmanager")
    public class Table {
        @Id
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "id_table", unique = true)
        private String id;

        @Column(name = "table_name")
        @NotNull
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "table_visible")
        private Integer visible;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_database")
        private Database database = new Database();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "table")
        private Set<Field> fields;
}
```

Field class

```
 @Entity
@javax.persistence.Table(name = "table_field", schema = "dbmanager")
public class Field {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id_field", unique = true)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "field_name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "field_visible")
    @NotNull
    private Integer visible;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_table")
    private Table table = new Table();
}
```

Comment: Can you add the save logic code please? So I can see what repository you use etc

Comment: 1. Don't initialize those fields yourself, that's a bad idea. 2. I think when you have @NotFound then hibernate treats it as EAGER, so LAZY is redundant.

Comment: @Ed0906, Thanx for you answer, I'm using here JPA repository with method save(T t) and thats all

Comment: What type of JPARepository? JpaRepository<....type..., ...ID type...>

Comment: public interface DatabaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Database, String>

Comment: Is this solved? I face the same issue

Comment: Im also facing the same issue with spring boot 3.0.1